# Изображение на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, изображения, css

Доброго времени суток, коллеги!

У меня проблема такая: хочу воткнуть под хэдер изображение, но у меня остаются отступы и слева и справа, вне зависимости от размера изображения.

Должно получиться как [здесь](https://twitter.com/googledevs)

Comment: http://frey.su/

наиболее наглядный пример того, как это должно выглядеть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там используеться изображение шириной 1440px

```
.class{
  background: #000 url(ВАШЕ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ) no-repeat center top;
  height: 500px;
}
```

вы скорее всего используете маленькое изображение или помещаете это изображение в блок у которого задана ширина

Comment: Все оказалось намного проще. Я забыл удалить container в одной вьюхе=) спасибо за отклик!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3UAfg/1/

Comment: этот код пробовал(еще до того как задавал вопрос) - не работает

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так http://jsfiddle.net/3UAfg/4/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте
http://jsfiddle.net/Vertigo/Szh8d/